# javascript or jquery: Looping a multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I just started playing around with JSON and I have created this example.

```
var shows = {

    "ShowA": 
                {   "Date"      : "November 3-5, 2011",
                    "Phone"     : "111-111-1111",
                    "Location"  : "some location",
                    "url"       : "http://www.showA.com"
                },

    "ShowB": 
                {   "Date"      : "January 15-18, 2012",
                    "Phone"     : "222-222-2222",
                    "Location"  : "another location",
                    "url"       : "http://www.showB.com"
                }

};
```

I figured out how to access each bit of information...ie: alert(shows.ShowA.Date);

However, I can't figure out how to loop the entire shows object in order alert each show and each show's properties. Do I need to change it to an array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use a [**for ... in loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for(var key in shows) {
    if (shows.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(shows[key].Date);
    }
}
```

It's important to note that an object has no sort order, but an array does. So if you wanted to sort by dates, you would need to use an array.

Also it's good practice to use [Object.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FhasOwnProperty)

Comment: Ah you saved my day.. This has been bugging me for an hour or so!

Answer (score 6):

```
for(show in shows){
     console.log(shows[show]);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Wp3N9/

No extra libraries needed ^_^

Comment: @yoda -- what *are* you talking about?