# Web page submit button that parses current page

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, post, cart

From the following web page code:

(Don't read through it now - just skip past it and take a look at what I'm needing to grab onto from the following code then you can come back to this code.)

```html
<table class="shop_table cart" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="product-name">Product</th>
      <th class="product-price">Price</th>
      <th class="product-quantity">Quantity</th>
      <th class="product-subtotal">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="cart_item">

      <td class="product-remove">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/cart/?remove_item=02e74f10e0327ad868d138f2b4fdd6f0&#038;_wpnonce=2eef060511" class="remove" title="Remove this item">&times;</a> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-thumbnail">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/product/5-htp-power/">
          <img width="90" height="90" src="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/product/2806-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="2806" />
        </a>
      </td>

      <td class="product-name">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/product/5-htp-power/">5-HTP Power</a> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-price">
        <span class="amount">&#36;19.55</span> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-quantity">
        <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" step="1" name="cart[02e74f10e0327ad868d138f2b4fdd6f0][qty]" value="35" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
        </div>
      </td>

      <td class="product-subtotal">
        <span class="amount">&#36;97.75</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cart_item">

      <td class="product-remove">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/cart/?remove_item=6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b&#038;_wpnonce=2eef060511" class="remove" title="Remove this item">&times;</a> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-thumbnail">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/product/5-w/">
          <img width="90" height="90" src="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/product/1120-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="1120" />
        </a>
      </td>

      <td class="product-name">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/product/5-w/">5-W</a> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-price">
        <span class="amount">&#36;19.35</span> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-quantity">
        <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" step="1" name="cart[6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b][qty]" value="104" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
        </div>
      </td>

      <td class="product-subtotal">
        <span class="amount">&#36;77.40</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cart_item">

      <td class="product-remove">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/cart/?remove_item=c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5&#038;_wpnonce=2eef060511" class="remove" title="Remove this item">&times;</a> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-thumbnail">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/product/7-keto/">
          <img width="90" height="90" src="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/product/2922-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="2922" />
        </a>
      </td>

      <td class="product-name">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/product/7-keto/">7-Keto</a> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-price">
        <span class="amount">&#36;38.25</span> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-quantity">
        <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" step="1" name="cart[c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5][qty]" value="3" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
        </div>
      </td>

      <td class="product-subtotal">
        <span class="amount">&#36;114.75</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cart_item">

      <td class="product-remove">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/cart/?remove_item=182be0c5cdcd5072bb1864cdee4d3d6e&#038;_wpnonce=2eef060511" class="remove" title="Remove this item">&times;</a> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-thumbnail">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/product/acidophilus/">
          <img width="90" height="90" src="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/product/1666-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="1666" />
        </a>
      </td>

      <td class="product-name">
        <a href="http://dev123.MyDomain.com/product/acidophilus/">Acidophilus</a> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-price">
        <span class="amount">&#36;15.95</span> 
      </td>

      <td class="product-quantity">
        <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" step="1" name="cart[182be0c5cdcd5072bb1864cdee4d3d6e][qty]" value="22" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
        </div>
      </td>

      <td class="product-subtotal">
        <span class="amount">&#36;31.90</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="actions">

        <div class="coupon">

          <label for="coupon_code">Coupon:</label>
          <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon code" />
          <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="Apply Coupon" />


        </div>
```

I need to grab onto the following items:

the 2806 part of alt="2806"

the   35 part of value="35" title="Qty"

the 1120 part of alt="1120"

the  104 part of value="104" title="Qty"

the 2922 part of alt="2922"

the    3 part of value="3" title="Qty"

the 1666 part of alt="1666"

the   22 part of value="22" title="Qty"

I have looked at this page:

[Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page)

and this page:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp

and I'm in a little bit over my head.

What I need to have is some javascript code that will result in... a variable that contains the following:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="prodnum" value="2806" />
<input type="hidden" name="prodqty" value="35" />
<input type="hidden" name="prodnum" value="1120" />
<input type="hidden" name="prodqty" value="104" />
<input type="hidden" name="prodnum" value="2922" />
<input type="hidden" name="prodqty" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="prodnum" value="1666" />
<input type="hidden" name="prodqty" value="22" />
```

I'm going to continue to struggle with this to see if I can figure it out myself but the odds are not in my favor.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you need the values to live in javascript and you have access to the data as the page renders why not just set the values? var prodnum1 = 2806; var prodqty1 =35; etc or Use an array to hold them all?

Comment: If you are submitting the data, the fields should be in a form. You can get all the controls in a form using its *elements* collection. So iterate over *form.elements* and collect the ones whose properties match the values you seek.

Comment: I'm trying to modify a free shopping cart page that was developed by a third party.  I don't really know PHP or Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using a three-dimensional javascript object:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6tm32t9f/)

```
var stObj = {};
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    var cnt = 0;
    $('.shop_table tbody tr:not(:last-child)').each(function(){
        //alert( this.className );
        cnt++;
        stObj[cnt] = {};
        $this = $(this);
        var thImg = $this.find('.product-thumbnail a img').attr('alt');
        //alert(thImg);
        var prQty = $this.find('.product-quantity div input').val();
        //alert(prQty);
        stObj[cnt]['thImg'] = thImg;
        stObj[cnt]['prQty'] = prQty;
    });
    alert( JSON.stringify(stObj) );
});
```

Notes:

(1) Object `stObj` is defined globally *(i.e. outside - above - the functions in which it is used)*

(2) jQuery selector `tr:not(:last-child)` prevents trying to find `alt` and `value` in last table row

*(3) In jsFiddle, the `#tst` div is immediately hidden by code. If visible, it just shows the code is broken without having to push any buttons.*

References:

[Multi-dimensional associative arrays in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329092/multi-dimensional-associative-arrays-in-javascript)

[javascript or jquery: Looping a multidimensional object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340060/javascript-or-jquery-looping-a-multidimensional-object)

Comment: Hi gibberish.  Thanks for posting that.  I took a look at it and it is definitely beyond my capabilities.  I do understand a little of it and I will probably understand it more - the more I reread it.

Comment: @user2792497 You might find these resources helpful for free 10-min video tutorials - tons of em:  [phpAcademy.org](https://phpacademy.org/videos/php-and-mysql-with-mysqli) and [theNewBoston.com](https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=32)