# Detect empty json values

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I'm trying to detect when I get all empty json values.

Here are 2 examples of empty json values.

```
json='{
  "data": [],
  "pagination": {
    "cursor": ""
  }
}'

json='{
    "data": [],
    "error": "",
    "message": "",
    "status": ""
}'
```

The closest I've gotten is this, which seems to work for the first example, but not the 2nd.

```
echo "$json" | jq -e 'all( .[] ; . == "" or . == [] or . == {}  )'
```

One, I thought easy way, would be to get the string text from each key pair, then just check if I'm left with an empty string. But I haven't found a way that works in the pagination example.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340060/javascript-or-jquery-looping-a-multidimensional-object

Comment: That is a possibility, but I was hoping there was a more compact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you `false` if all `strings` and `arrays` are `""` or `[]`:

```bash
jq -e 'all(.. | strings, arrays; IN("", [])) | not'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OiOR4-CCosy)

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! Thank you so much.

Comment: Note: Applying [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), the filter can also be expressed using `any` by bringing `not` inside to act on `IN`: `any(.. | strings, arrays; IN("", []) | not)`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good use for [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron)

```bash
json='{
  "data": [],
  "pagination": {
    "cursor": "",
    "position":[2,3]
  }
}'
```

gron transforms the input JSON into discrete paths:

```bash
$ gron <<< "$json"
json = {};
json.data = [];
json.pagination = {};
json.pagination.cursor = "";
json.pagination.position = [];
json.pagination.position[0] = 2;
json.pagination.position[1] = 3;
```

and to test for any non-empty elements

```bash
$ gron <<< "$json" | grep -Evq '(\{\}|\[\]|"");$' && echo "not everything is empty"
not everything is empty
```

Comment: Oh wow, `gron` is pretty cool, learn something new every day!